# UI Does Not Show Values From Initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization

Trying to pass default values to instance of ViewController object. The code compiles without warning and I step through and see values being set, however, when app launches the values on UI are back to zero. It's as if I'm creating two distinct instances, but for the life of me can't figure why initialized value are not part of launched application. Here's implementation and main.m code. Any help is appreciated.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    @autoreleasepool {
        ViewController *viewController;
        viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithBinauralFrequencyLeft:82.4
                                                        binauralFreqRight:82.4 
                                                              octaveValue:1
                                                         baseScaleSetting:82.4
                                                       binauralBaseVolume:800
                                                      globalBaseSongCount:0];
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));




        //[pool release];
        return retVal;
    }
}

-(id)initWithBinauralFrequencyLeft:(double)binauralFreqL
             binauralFreqRight:(double)binauralFreqR
                   octaveValue:(double)octaveVal
              baseScaleSetting:(double)baseScaleSet
            binauralBaseVolume:(int)binauralVolume
           globalBaseSongCount:(int)globalSongCount;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
    [self setBinauralFreqL:82.4];
    [self setBinauralFreqR:82.4];
    [self setOctaveVal:1];
    [self setBaseScaleSet:82.4];
    [self setBinauralVolume:800];
    [self setGlobalSongCount:0];   
}
return self;
}

-(id)init
{
   return [self initWithBinauralFrequencyLeft:82.4 binauralFreqRight:82.4 octaveValue:1              baseScaleSetting:82.4 binauralBaseVolume:800 globalBaseSongCount:0];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the ViewController is actually being instantiated from your AppDelegate.m file - check in there. It's probably just sending the standard init message, rather than your customised one.

I don't think the ViewController should be created before the call to UIApplicationMain.

Comment: Ok then. I thought it might be a sequence thing. I will examine AppDelegate methods. Thank you!